# Disabled field name in edit profile joomla

Tags: php, css, joomla

I want to disable the fields, name and last name, in edit profile Joomla, so that user can not modify them. How can I change this?

[image: edit profile]

Answer (score 2):

The best approach, but not the easiest, is to create an user plugin to override form with a onContentPrepareForm method :

```
public function onContentPrepareForm($form, $data){

    if (!($form instanceof JForm)){
        $this->_subject->setError('JERROR_NOT_A_FORM');
        return false;
    }

    $form->setFieldAttribute('name', 'readonly', 'true');
    $form->setFieldAttribute('lastname', 'readonly', 'true');

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a configuration setting to achieve this.
So the easiest approach is to create a template override for the users view.

In the administrator, open the menu Extensions-Templates-Templates, then select your template and choose "Create Overrides" in the top tab:
[image: Joomla override page]

In the center column, choose com_users - profile and edit.php [image: override code]

The display is done with a loop, starting at line 59 (as of v. 3.6.5) you want to add code to identify the fields you wish to keep readonly, and simply set their readonly property.

This is the kind of code you would add starting at line 59:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $field) : ?>
        <?php 
            if ($field->name == 'jform[name]') {
              $field->readonly = true;
            }
        ?>
        <?php // If the field is hidden, just display the input. ?>
```

The $field contains something like this:
[image]

We are identifying it by name (well by its field name), then setting its `readonly` property.